# How can a user find out their quality control rating?

Tags: support, review-audits

While reviewing some first-post questions and answers, I happened across one of the quality control items (good answer, so I upvoted, and was told that it had been a quality control test).

So, I'm wondering, is there a way that users can find out what their quality control score or stats are without coming to meta to ask (and possibly be told, "Sorry, not allowed to tell you sparky.")?  Or is it better for users to not know their quality control score, and thus just continuously strive for high quality in reviews?

Motivation being a very individual thing, some might be satisfied with "meh" quality control, but if I were to learn that my score was other than perfect, it would drive me to try harder while reviewing to make sure that I was being accurate in my reviews.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you can't check on that.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg Is there any way that someone could look it up?  Or is it all housed on the automation-side of the house and nobody has access to it?

Comment: @killermist even moderators don't see a specific score. We can just see if a user is currently banned from reviewing or not, and you would know if you were banned. All of the metrics are internal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to see your own review *audit* history, although you can see your review history from your user profile under activity > reviews.

Moderators can see whether a specific user is currently banned from reviewing or not, and can see recently passed and failed review audits. Review audit history is only available for the past 30 days though and only provides a general overview.

There is no specific "score" with review audits, only a limit to how many you can fail in a specific time period. Review bans are automatically lifted after a certain time, and review audits are only considered over a 30 day window. The exact number of failures that lead to a temporary ban isn't publicly published.

As long as you're mostly passing audits, and stopping to think about why you might've failed if you do fail an audit, you're fine. There's no permanent score or record on your profile.

For slightly more details, see the FAQ on Meta Stack Overflow about review audits:

**[What are review tests (audits) and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work)**